# What does «acerto electrónico de chaves» mean?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras

I find *acerto* meaning *hit*, but in this case does *acerto* mean to get a copy of keys, reprogramming keys, or anything else?

Comment: Do you have a context to that expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check meaning 4. from [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/acerto):

> **4.** *Mec.* Regulagem de máquina, motor etc., para que funcione perfeitamente.

*Acerto* could indeed be a form of the verb [*acertar*](http://www.aulete.com.br/acertar) (indicative, present, first person, singular), but not here. In that case, it would be pronounced with an [open *e*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_unrounded_vowel), rather than the [closed one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_front_unrounded_vowel) of the noun *acerto*.

Comment: I think the answer would be stronger if it showed the concrete meaning of the whole expression.

Comment: I agree that meaning 4 is the most relevant among those in Aulete, but I still don't understand what «acerto eletrónico de chaves» means. Then there's the side issue of *acerto* as *hit*. *Acerto* is the act of *acertar*. But even though one of the meanings of *acertar* is *to hit*, we don't use  *acerto* to mean the *act of hitting*, only the act of *acertar* in its other meanings. I think  the OP was referring to the possibility of *acerto* meaning *the act of hitting*, not *(eu) acerto*.

Comment: @Jacinto I don't see any reason to think the OP thought that _acerto_ meant _hit_ (noun) due to it generally being the act of _acertar_. That requires quite a bit more sophisticated thought when compared to the OP just having been exposed to _acerto_ as a verb. As to what _acerto eletrónico de chaves_ means we can only guess (the OP gave no context, for instance we don't know whether the keys themselves are electronic), and therefore I did not expand on that.

Comment: @ANeves See also above ^^

Comment: @Jacinto Also, _acerto_ is not strictly an act of _acertar_ here (or at least _acertar_ in the sense of _adjusting a machine_ is quite rare), so that explanation would only bring further confusion.

Comment: I agree about the "acerto". I still think the answer could be improved with the concrete meaning. Additionally, I think it's irrelevant whether the keys are electronic or analogic, and wether they're made of metal, ivory, or wax. But I **do** find the answer useful, and it did seem to clear the doubts that the asker had - because it was accepted.

Comment: *Acerto* is a noun in «acerto eletrónico de chaves». That's why I think the OP means a noun in «I find acerto meaning hit». Google will (poorly) translate it as a noun too. But @ANeves, you appear to know what that «acerto eletrónico de chaves» is.

Comment: @Jacinto a machine, electronic and automatic (as opposed to manually-controlled), that corrects keys. It probably corrects a bad (or worn-down) copy, by analyzing the original.

Comment: @ANeves well you've just shown it does matter whether they are electronic or not, as your conjecture requires them not to be so.

Answer (score 2):

*Acerto eletronico de chaves* seems to be the translation from the english term [key establishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_exchange) used in computer communications. When 2 or more computers want to exchange data in a secure way, they first have to agree on a common key to be used in a cryptographic protocol. This may sound as a paradox, but there are [ways to exchange secrets over a public communications channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange).

As soon as the communicating computers agree on a key to use on a secure protocol, they have an *acerto eletronico de chaves*. Thus the most appropriate meaning from *acerto* as from [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/acerto) is number 2:

```
2. Aquilo que se combinou; ACORDO; COMBINAÇÃO
```

Comment: Não o chegaste a afirmar que *acerto eletrónico de chaves* é correntemente usado com esse significado. É?

Comment: @Jacinto, Normalmente eu leio outras expressões tais como _acordo de chaves_ ou _estabelecimento de chaves_. Não recordo ter lido _acerto de chaves_. Mesmo assim creio que o sentido seja o que descrevi acima. Talvez um pouco mais de contexto por parte do OP possa ser útil.

Comment: Eu também acho a tua interpretação plausível, mas de facto sem mais contexto não é possível ter certezas. Perguntei porque fiquei na dúvida se não tinhas sido definitivo por desatenção ou reserva.